# Display Multiple Content Types on New Item Link on Custom List SharePoint 2016

Tags: content-type, custom-list

I have three content types attached to a custom list. I would like to display them as a drop-down when clicking on "New Item" similar to what you see when using a Document Library with multiple content types. Does anyone have some sample code that does this?  See Screenshot.
[image]

Thanks, Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

You can gain this functionality in the menu ribbon under the 'New Item' option there without code by ensuring that your content types are enabled to be "Visible on New Button" in the Content Type section of your list settings (see screenshots). Does this meet your needs?

[image: Example of Content Type options in New Item option in the menu ribbon]

[image: Example of Content Type settings for making them visible in the option above]

Cheers,

-Drew

Comment: Not exactly meets my needs.  Users will click on "New Item" which will use the "default content type", However, I have three content types and they would like the "New Item" to act as a drop-down so they can choose the correct content type (without using the Ribbon)